# How do show the 5 objects in my ArrayList?

Tags: java

Goal - Write a class named PhoneBookEntry that has fields for a person's name and phone number. The class should have a constructor and appropriate accessor and mutator methods. Then write a program that created at least five PhoneBookEntry objects and stores them in an ArrayList. Use a loop to display the contents of each object in the ArrayList.

Code -

```
package phonebook;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhoneBookEntry {
    public PhoneBookEntry(String personName, int phoneNumber) {
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> phoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>();
        
        PhoneBookEntry Jack = new PhoneBookEntry("Jack Daniel", 678-439-5823);
        PhoneBookEntry Dave = new PhoneBookEntry("Dave Daniel", 366-263-1363);
        PhoneBookEntry John = new PhoneBookEntry("John Daniel", 404-642-8642);
        PhoneBookEntry Judy = new PhoneBookEntry("Judy Daniel", 232-952-9142);
        PhoneBookEntry Jennifer = new PhoneBookEntry("Jennifer Daniel", 563-124-8246);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < phoneBook.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(phoneBook.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Problem - The program has no issue that prevents it from producing, however, it's not showing the 5 objects through a loop.

Comment: You don't add the objects you create to the `phoneBook` list. You have to use the `add()` method.

Comment: You're never adding them to the array mate...

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding your objects to your ArrayList.
Use: `phoneBook.add(OBJECT)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> phoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>();

    phoneBook.add(new PhoneBookEntry("Jack Daniel", 678-439-5823));
    //etc..
        
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneBook.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(phoneBook.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all of the elements to the `ArrayList`. To simplify this, you can use `Arrays.asList`.

```
ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> phoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>(
   Arrays.asList(new PhoneBookEntry("Jack Daniel", 678-439-5823),
        new PhoneBookEntry("Dave Daniel", 366-263-1363),
        new PhoneBookEntry("John Daniel", 404-642-8642),
        new PhoneBookEntry("Judy Daniel", 232-952-9142),
        new PhoneBookEntry("Jennifer Daniel", 563-124-8246)
   )
);
```

If you want to keep the variable names:

```
ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry> phoneBook = new ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>(
   Arrays.asList(Jack, Dave, John, Judy, Jennifer)
);
```